LPD print jobs getting lost
I am managing a client's system which prints to multiple remote printers. Some are connected to PC's and shared, so on the server they are configured as smb printers.
There are two network attached line printers that are configured on lpd ports. They don't support IPP or SMB.
Print jobs work fine on all during the day time; they print as desired. All of them get powered off at night. CUPS keeps the jobs in queue for them till the next time they get powered up and a script issues cupsenable commands to re-enable them. Right now I can see jobs queued on a couple of printers for the last 3 days.
However, for the line printers the jobs are not being printed. Some jobs run at night and generate spool files. From CUPS log, I see that those files got sent to the device. When the office opens in the morning, the queues for just those two printers is empty.
The server runs Oracle Linux 9.4
Is there something in lpd policy that cannot check if the printer is responding and causing jobs to get lost?
